# Cant expand second level of menu

Tags: html, jquery

Im a jquery noob and I cant figure out how to get the next level expanding in a clickable accordion like menu.

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hinterseer/gaxm6uqo/29/

Html

```
<div class="navbar-collapse">
 <ul class="nav">
  <li class="subMenu">Archive <span class="caret toggle">+</span>
   <ul class="subMenu-link">
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="subMenu"> Archive 2 <span class="caret toggle">+</span>
   <ul class="subMenu-link">
    <li class="subMenu">Archive 3 <span class="caret toggle">+</span>
      <ul class="subMenu-link">
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.subMenu-link {
  display: none;
 }

.subMenu {
  list-style: none;
 }
```

jQyery

```
(function($) {


  $("li.subMenu").unbind().click(function () {
      var slideDown = $(this).find(".toggle").text() == "+" ? false : true;
      $(".subMenu-link").slideUp();
      $(".toggle").text('+');


      if (!slideDown) {
          $(this).find('.subMenu-link').slideDown();
          $(this).find('.toggle').text('-');

      }
  });



})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've refactored things a bit further to enable toggling of each list item and their children independently. I've listed the changes below:

- change the listener to `$(".toggle").on('click', function() {...`
- change `slideDown` to `const` and modify selector `$(this).find(".caret:first")...`
- use `.siblings()` for slide up/down functionality, `$(this).siblings(".subMenu-link").slideUp()`
- restructure HTML to wrap `li` text in its own `span` so that the text triggers the toggle instead of the whole element (and its children)
- add `cursor: pointer` to `.toggle` for visual cue to user indicating click

Saw this and thought I'd give things a shot even if it was more than asked.

```js
(function($) {


  $(".toggle").on('click', function() {
    const slideDown = $(this).find(".caret:first").text() == "+" ? false : true;
    $(this).siblings(".subMenu-link").slideUp();
    $(this).find(".caret").text('+');


    if (!slideDown) {
      $(this).siblings('.subMenu-link').slideDown();
      $(this).find('.caret').text('-');
    }
  });



})(jQuery);
```

```css
.subMenu-link {
  display: none;
}

.subMenu {
  list-style: none;
}

.toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="subMenu"><span class="toggle">Archive <span class="caret">+</span></span>
      <ul class="subMenu-link">
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="subMenu"><span class="toggle">Archive 2 <span class="caret">+</span></span>
      <ul class="subMenu-link">
        <li class="subMenu"><span class="toggle">Archive 3 <span class="caret">+</span></span>
          <ul class="subMenu-link">
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, good job, it's so much better than my fast answer :).

Comment: Much obliged sir!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `:first` in this line:

`var slideDown = $(this).find(".toggle:first").text() == "+" ? false : true;`

Comment: if it wasn't for corona, I would give you some luvin ;)